# Unable to fetch Integration Tests results from Sonar WS API

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I'm preparing a customized report of metrices present on SonarQube Dashboard, predominantly, Unit Test & Integration Test execution & coverage matrix. I succeed in getting it for Unit Tests but it seems there are no matrics keys available to fetch Integration & overall coverage statistics. I'm using SonarQube 4.5.6. Please also guide me if there is another way to export the Sonar Dashboard Stats as HTML. The code is as follows:

```
public class TestStatistics{
    static String host = "http://my.server.com/Sonar";
    static String login = "admin";
    static String password = "admin";       
    static String resourceKey = "shift:shift";
    static String[] MEASURES_TO_GET =  new String[]{"branch_coverage",
         "new_branch_coverage",
         "branch_coverage_hits_data",
         "conditions_by_line",
         "covered_conditions_by_line",
         "coverage",
         "new_coverage",
         "line_coverage",
         "new_line_coverage",
         "coverage_line_hits_data",
         "lines_to_cover",
         "new_lines_to_cover",
         "skipped_tests",
         "uncovered_conditions",
         "new_uncovered_conditions",
         "uncovered_lines",
         "new_uncovered_lines",
         "tests",
         "test_execution_time",
         "test_errors",
         "test_failures",
         "test_success_density"
         };

    public static void main(String[] args) {                
        try {       
            Date date = new Date();

            Sonar sonar = new Sonar(new HttpClient4Connector(new Host(host, login, password)));
            ResourceQuery query = ResourceQuery.createForMetrics(resourceKey, MEASURES_TO_GET);
            query.setIncludeTrends(true);
            List<Resource> resources = sonar.findAll(query);
            for(Resource resource:resources){
                List<Measure> allMeasures = resource.getMeasures();
                System.out.println("All Measures : "+allMeasures.toString());
                System.out.println("Unit Branch Coverage : "+resource.getMeasureValue("branch_coverage"));
                System.out.println("Unit Test Coverage : "+resource.getMeasureValue("coverage"));
                System.out.println("Unit Line Coverage : "+resource.getMeasureValue("line_coverage"));
                System.out.println("Lines To Cover : "+resource.getMeasureValue("lines_to_cover"));
                System.out.println("Skipped Tests : "+resource.getMeasureValue("skipped_tests"));
                System.out.println("Uncovered Conditions : "+resource.getMeasureValue("uncovered_conditions"));
                System.out.println("Uncovered Lines : "+resource.getMeasureValue("uncovered_lines"));
                System.out.println("Unit Tests : "+resource.getMeasureValue("tests"));
                System.out.println("Unit Test Execution Time : "+resource.getMeasureValue("test_execution_time"));
                System.out.println("Unit Tests Errors : "+resource.getMeasureValue("test_errors"));
                System.out.println("Unit Tests Failures : "+resource.getMeasureValue("test_failures"));
                System.out.println("Unit Tests Success Density : "+resource.getMeasureValue("test_success_density"));
            }
               System.out.println("DONE");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Use `api/metrics` Web API to list available metrics (and get details such as *key*, *name*, *type* etc.).

- In SonarQube 4.5.6: [api/metrics](http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392172)
- Since SonarQube 5.2: [api/metrics/search](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/web_api/api/metrics/search) ([example](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/metrics/search))

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer.

All the metrics' keys are stored in a table called matrics under sonarqube database.

Now, Another silly thing that I failed to observe earlier is that, if we hover over a specific statistics displayed in sonarqube dashboard, it will reveal the key of the metric.

Thanks a lot StackOverFlow.

All the keys for Integration & overall test execution statistics are as follows:
it_coverage, 
it_line_coverage, 
it_uncovered_lines, 
it_branch_coverage, 
it_uncovered_conditions, 
overall_coverage, 
overall_line_coverage, 
overall_uncovered_lines, 
overall_branch_coverage, 
overall_uncovered_conditions

Comment: Fetching this information in the database is overkill (and unreliable as DB structure may change depending on versions), you should use the Web Services instead (see other answer).